# Ударения в "Сказке о мёртвой царевне и семи богатырях" А. С. Пушкина

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, поэзия, пушкин

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно ставить ударения в строках "Сказки о мёртвой царевне и семи богатырях" А. С. Пушкина?

*Ждёт-пождёт с утра до ночи,

Смотрит в поле, инда очи

Разболелись глядючи

С белой зори до ночи...*

Интересуют слова "глядючи" – "ночи".
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Вне стихотворной формы ударение в слове ***глядючи*** только такое ([Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8&mode=all)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**до́ ночи, до но́чи** ([Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274681/%D0%B4%D0%BE))

А вот Пушкин в своей сказке, видимо, ставил по-другому.
Справочная служба ([Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/279537)) на этот вопрос отвечает так:

> В "Словаре языка Пушкина" (М., 2000): *глядючИ*.

Сейчас, наверно, редко кто выберет такой вариант ударения.
На слух привычнее так, как [читает](http://staroeradio.ru/audio/17386), например, Алиса Фрейндлих:

*Ждёт-пождёт с утра до н**о́**чи,

Смотрит в поле, инда **о́**чи

Разболелись гл**я́**дючи

С белой зори д**о́** ночи...*

Правильных или неправильных ударений в этом случае быть не может.

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии **с размером**  правильно вроде бы так:

*Ждёт-по/ждёт  с ут/рА до /нОчи,

Смотрит /в поле, /инда / о́чи

Разбо/лЕлись /**глЯдю**/чи

С белой /зОри / **дО но**/чи...*

Это **двусложный хорей**, ударение на первом слоге.

Можно, наверное,  прочитать так (пушкинский вариант, тоже укладывается в размер):

*Разбо/лелись / **глядю/чИ**

С белой/ зори/  **до  но/ чИ**...*

Нашла такое **[объяснение:](https://mitrius.livejournal.com/460182.html)**

*Как это понимать? Как **мужскую рифму** **"глядючИ — ночИ"** (это самое естественное, т. к. по всей сказке чётко выдержана последовательность клаузул **жжмм**; но при том что такое ударение в первом слове очень необычно, а для сочетания "до ночи" чуть выше Пушкин даёт другое ударение.*

Comment: я послушал пластинки, все в основном читают: Смотрит в поле.../ инда очи разболелись глЯдючи/ с белой зори дО ночи... Кроме как на Азбуке, там девушка с молодым голосом ставит ударение глядючИ доночИ https://azbyka.ru/fiction/skazka-o-mjortvoj-carevne-i-o-semi-bogatyrjah/

Comment: прикол в советском мультфильме 1951 года, там вторую строфу просто выкинули с сразу третью начали) ну там не только её, там вообще части стихов нет.

Comment: На Азбуке мне не нравится чтение сказки: очень пафосно, не сказочно, много ударений. Как молоточками по голове)  // При ударении глядючИ  в первой части слова обычно нет редукции, отчетливо проговаривается Я,  как бы  делается вспомогательное ударение.  Получается классно, по-пушкински.  Мне нравится.